# get control of input text type and click

Tags: html, jquery

I have a input tag with type text and textarea.I want to get jquery control on end of typing in input tag and on click of textarea.

I have tried with keyup on input text tag and click on textarea but the keyup is triggered for each letter i type I want it to trigger once I complete the entire type on input text tag and then click on textarea

```js
$( "#sub-proj" ).keyup(function() {
  $("#description").click(function(){
  console.log('clicked')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="sub-proj"  placeholder="Project Name" maxlength="50" required="required"/><br/>
              <textarea  rows="4" cols="45" id="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
```

Comment: What is `end of input`? A special letter ?

Comment: no not any special character

Comment: Then if focusing out indicates end of input , use `change` instead of `keyup`

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you mean to call/trigger something after you stop typing on the input field. You can set a typing timer. Let's assume you stop typing for about 3 seconds. Timer starts every time a key is pressed then it'll reset if another one is pressed.

```
var typingtimer;

$('#input').keydown(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingtimer); 
   typingtimer = setTimeout(doSomething, 3000);
});

function doSomething() {
    alert('execute things');
}
```